# Deploying to Google app Engine - AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 2

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot application to Google App Engine but can't seem to figure out this exception.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:deploy (default-cli) on project HowlingWolfe: App Engine application deployment failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 2 -> [Help 1]
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.HowlingWolfe</groupId>
    <artifactId>HowlingWolfe</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>HowlingWolfe</name>
    <description>Howling Wolfe Canoe and Kayak Rentals</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties> 

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <deploy.version>1.0</deploy.version>
                    <project>thehowlingwolfe</project>
                    <deploy.promote>true</deploy.promote>
                    <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and my app.yml:

```
runtime: java
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored

health_check: 
  enable_health_check: False
```

I don't usually use yaml files but GAE kept giving me exceptions for not having one. I googled to current contents of it, so maybe that is the problem? Anything I should add/remove?
Something else I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like is something related to the `pom.xml` configuration. Take a look in this [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/flexible/helloworld-springboot) code where it's important how you [declare](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/flexible/helloworld-springboot#deploy-to-app-engine-flexible-environment) the `projectId`.